PubSub error: Property 'asyncIterator' does not exist on type 'PubSub<Record<string, never>>'.ts(2339)
This happens in my Nestjs app, when I use simple code:
import { PubSub } from 'graphql-subscriptions';

export const pubSub = new PubSub();

@Subscription(() => ChatModel, {
    name: 'chatSent',
    filter: function (this: ChatResolver, payload, variables, context) {
      return this.chatService.filterChatSentEvent(payload, user);
    },
  })
  chatSent() {
    return pubSub.asyncIterator('chatSent');
  }

Packages I use:
 "graphql": "^16.10.0",
 "graphql-subscriptions": "^3.0.0",


Seems like new version of graphql-subscription uses asyncIterableIterator, so correct usage is:
 return pubSub.asyncIterableIterator('chatSent');

This is noticeable by inspecting type definitions:
PubSub extends PubSubEngine

PubSubEngine class implements:
asyncIterableIterator<T>(triggers: string | readonly string[]): PubSubAsyncIterableIterator<T>;

In npm package "graphql-subscriptions", both asyncIterator and asyncIterableIterator are used (description is probably not updated).

Also see https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/4556#issuecomment-1051126742
